# Find a constant $\lambda > 0$ so that the matrix is invertible provided $|a|, |b|, |c| < \lambda$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a constant $\lambda > 0$ so that the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & 0 \\ b & 1 & c \\ c & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

is invertible provided $|a|<\lambda$, $|b|<\lambda$ and $|c|<\lambda$.

---

I calculated the determinant in terms of $a, b,c$ and I got $1 - a(b - c^2)$, which means the matrix is not invertible provided $a(b - c)^2 = 1$.

Hence, we have the inequality $|a(b - c^2)| < 1$. But,

$$|a(b - c^2)| < |\lambda(\lambda - \lambda^2)| = |\lambda^2 - \lambda^3|.$$

Equating to $1$ to get the bound, we find $\lambda(\lambda - \lambda^2) = 1$, and we can rearrange to get $\lambda(\lambda - \lambda^2) - 1 = 0$. Wolfram Alpha says the solution between $0$ and $1$ is $-0.75488$. Does that mean I can take $\lambda = 0.75488$ to be my answer?

I don't know if this is right because I had to use a calculator for the cubic equation, and none of the exercises I've done so far out of this book have required a calculator. So maybe there's some better way? Or maybe my answer is just wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot go from $|a|,|b|,|c|<\lambda$ to $|a(b-c^2)|<|\lambda(\lambda-\lambda^2)|$. For instance, take $\lambda=0.5$, $a=b=0.4$, and $c=0$. Then $|a(b-c^2)|=0.16$ while $|\lambda(\lambda-\lambda^2)| = 0.125$.

Comment: Ok got it. So I end up getting $\lambda^2 + \lambda^3 < 1$, which gives me $\lambda = 0.75488$

Comment: @wutv1922: Not quite. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By triangle inequality, we have $$\bigl|a(b-c^2)\bigr|=\bigl|ab-ac^2\bigr|\le|ab|+\bigl|ac^2\bigr|=|a||b|+|a||c|^2<\lambda^2+\lambda^3,$$ so it suffices to find $\lambda>0$ such that $$\lambda^2+\lambda^3<1.\tag{$\star$}$$

The fact that Wolfram Alpha gave you a negative answer should be a good indication to you that something went wrong in your approach, and unfortunately, $0.75488$ doesn't do the trick, since $$0.75488^2+0.75488^3=1.000007513014272>1.$$ However, there are infinitely-many viable $\lambda$ that you can pick. You just need to make sure that it's positive and satisfies $(\star).$

Alternatively, you could use the exact form $$x = \frac{1}{3}\left(-1 + \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}\left(25 - 3\sqrt{69}\right)} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}\left(25 + 3\sqrt{69}\right)}\right)$$ of the real solution to $x^3+x^2=1,$ and simply say $\lambda\in(0,x),$ so you don't even *have* to choose!

Comment: Ok. I understand now, thanks.